# How to change the value format for a specific column - R

Tags: r, integer, numbers, decimal

Suppose that I have a dataset `traffic` with a column `Traffic_count` that displays the traffic count for each traffic counting station:

| Traffic_counting_station_ID | Traffic_count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 24.592 |
| 2 | 65.500 |
| 3 | 4.976 |

The problem is that `Traffic_count` is interpreted as a float type while the values should represent integer numbers. As an example, when I generate a new column `Traffic_count_TimesTen` which is formulated as `traffic$Traffic_count*10`, the resulting table is:

| Traffic_counting_station_ID | Traffic_count | Traffic_count_TimesTen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 24.592 | 245.92 |
| 2 | 65.500 | 655.00 |
| 3 | 4.976 | 49.76 |

When I apply `traffic$Traffic_count <- as.integer(traffic$Traffic_count)` the values for `Traffic_count` will just be 25, 66 and 5 respectively.

Applying `traffic$Traffic_count <- as.numeric(gsub(".","",traffic$Traffic_count))` to remove the point that defines the type float, results in `NA`.

How can I convert the values of Traffic_count to integer numbers so that the values in `Traffic_count` are regarded as 24592, 65500, 4976 and the values in `Traffic_count_TimesTen` are regarded as 245920, 655000 and 49760?

Comment: Multiply by 1000

Comment: The multiplication by 1000 is correct, as long as all the numbers have 3 digits right of the dot. If not, I would suggest a more general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `gsub` solution is almost correct.Try the following:

```r
traffic$Traffic_count <- as.numeric(gsub("\\.","",traffic$Traffic_count))
```

### Explanation

`.` is a special sign in regex, meaning "any" character, therefore it will replace every letter with `""`. If you exlicitly want to replace a dot, you need to put a `\` in front of it. But as R tries to interpret a single "" within a string we need to tell R itself not to preprocess the slash with another slash. therefore  `\\`